# What is the mistake in balancing the equation in a demonstration that $0.999\ldots=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, decimal-expansion

What is the mistake in balancing this equation? It says $.99999 = 1$, in step 3 $x$ is subtracted from the left side and $.99999$ from the right side. Shouldn't that mean there is some division by $0$ stopping the equation from being right?

[image: Equation]

Comment: I don't see an issue: nowhere it's being stated that $0.99999=1$; these are all valid manipulations around the true statement that $0.\overline 9=1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: In this proof that $1=2$, $a$ can't equal $b$, does the same thing happen in this proof $1$ equals $.9$ repeating? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hI9CaQD7P6I

Comment: @arclengths, the fatal mistake in the youtube "proof" that $1=2$ comes when the factor $(a-b)$ is cancelled from both sides of the equation $(a+b)(a-b)=b(a-b)$, because $a-b=0$. In the proof here, the factor being cancelled is $9$, and $9$ is *not* equal to $0$, so the cancellation is OK.

Comment: I agree with the posts in the linked question that this approach to proving the equality of $0.9999\dots$ and $1$ is invalid as it makes assumptions as to the allowed operations when manipulating these infinite expressions or makes a circular argument as manipulating $\frac{1}{3}=0.3333\dots$ or $\frac{1}{9}=0.11111\dots$ which if the initial identity is in question then these other identities should also be questioned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in these proofs. Both of them are completely valid and proof that $1 = 0.9999\dots$. This statement is, indeed, true. This can be sometimes confusing to people and it's completely normal that it feels weird at first.

If you think about it in the following way, it might make sense: What would $1-0.9999\dots$ be? The difference between these two numbers is smaller then any rational number. The only number that is smaller than any other is $0$. Thus: $1-0.9999\dots = 0$, which implies $1 = 0.9999\dots$.

Comment: Well,  unless we expand into a non-Archimedean field...

Comment: I think this is not the intended scope of this question. But, of course, you're right.